# Using different variables with the same name in different templates

Tags: meteor

I have two templates, which are included into some layout template:

```
{{>b_afisha_today}}
{{>b_afisha_soon}}
```

I want to use some variable in helpers for one of my templates.

```
Template.b_afisha_today.onCreated(function() {
    this.data.day = new Date().getDate();
}

Template.b_afisha_today.helpers({
    times: function() {
        var day = Template.instance().data.day;
    }
})
```

The problem here is that Template.instance().data.day is now belongs to the parent layout template (and to the global scope I guess). So, if I initialize a new variable with the same name in my second template, it will change everything in my first template.

```
Template.b_afisha_soon.onCreated(function() {
    this.data.day = 'mess everything';
}
```

Not sure if it is possible to use two independant variables with the same name, each is accessable within one template?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from parent template to child template like this.

```
<div class="slot-wrapper">
  {{> b_afisha_today day=day}}
  {{> b_afisha_soon day=day}}
  ...
</div>

<template name="b_afisha_today">
  <div class="day"><span>{{day}}</span></div>
</template>

<template name="b_afisha_soon">
  <div class="day"><span>{{day}}</span></div>
</template>
```

I hope that can solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't. There are different parent templates. I just can't (and don't want) generate data and pass it to my templates from parents. I think it should be some way to scope variables inside templates.